# Some equivalence relations on $S^1 \times S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $S^1: x^2+y^2=1$ be the circle ; $S^2: x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ be the sphere; then define also $X= S^1 \times S^2$

1. I want to define an equivalence relation on $X$ such that $X/\sim$ is **not** a top manifold.
2. I want to define a non trivial equivalence relation on $X$ such that $X/\sim$ **is** a top manifold.

I think I can picture $X$ as a sphere revolving around some centre following an orbit which is given by $S^1.$ In other words what I have is a family of spheres parametrized by $S^1.$

For (1), I can identify $E\times (\cos0 , \sin0) \sim E \times (\cos \pi, \sin\pi)$ where $E$ is   some point on the equator of the sphere. So that the sphere is moving on an 8 figure, but on the connecting point of the 8 i get two spheres glued by the point $E.$ I think now a neighborhood of $(E,(\cos0 , \sin0))$ will have two connected components, hence this space is not locally euclidean.

For (2), if I identify all the points $$S^2 \times {(\cos 0,\sin0)} \sim S^2 \times (\cos \pi/2, \sin/2 \pi) \sim S^2 \times (\cos \pi, \sin \pi) \sim S^2 \times (\cos 3/2\pi, \sin 3/2\pi) \sim S^2 \times (\cos 2 \pi, \sin 2\pi)$$ what I get is a sphere parametrized by an interval, which is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^2$ and hence is a topological manifold.

I would like to know first of all if my reasonings make sense and only secondly some alternative simpler/ better solutions.

Comment: Two things: (a) your identifications are on $\mathcal{S}^2\times\mathcal{S}^1$, not $\mathcal{S}^1\times\mathcal{S}^2$; this is a trivial change but it's worth noting. (b) I _think_ what you're suggesting for part 2 works (without looking closely), but there are much easier ones: consider a 'trivial nontrivial' equivalence relation that collapses $X$ onto one of its compoennts.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you! For (a) I was just careless in writing down the text. For (b) I agree with you about the trivial non trivial relation you suggest. But this works only for point 2 which is the easier of the two and the one I am more confident about.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ah maybe for (1) I can collapse everything to $S^1$ and then pinch $S^1$ to get an 8 which is not a top. variety.

Comment: For (1) if $X$ is any $T_1$ space with at least two points and $p\in X$ is not isolated, then $X/(X\backslash\{p\})$, i.e. collapsing $X\backslash\{p\}$ to a point is never a manifold. It has two points but one of them is not open.